# "Delete" button on my answer does nothing, Safari 15.4, but works in Chrome

Tags: bug, safari

I don't know if SO Meta is the best or worst place to post this, but the "Delete" button/link that appears below a posted answer (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72037429/182668) ) generally lets the answerer delete the question. In this case I wanted to because Bergi had posted a better answer just before mine.

However, in Safari, that "Delete" button does nothing whatsoever. I get no confirmation popup, no error in the console, nothing.

On the same laptop, I can bring up Chrome, go to the same question, and the "Delete" button works fine.

*edit* — I clicked "Edit" to update this question. On my linked answer above, the "Delete" button now works. However, the "Cancel" button on *this* page, while I am currently typing, does not work! I'm really confused. I am not an experienced MacOS user, so maybe this is something Safari does now and then.

*edit again* — aaand now it works (the "Cancel" button). I noticed that when it was *not* working I'd see a little box at the bottom of the screen that said "Run script void(0)" or something like that.

Comment: Does your browsers network log show that a call is being made, and if so is it being blocked by something (like an adblocker or safari's builtin tracker protection)?

Comment: @vandench no. The JavaScript console shows nothing, and the Network tab shows nothing.